# Pythonic way of comparing all adjacent elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if there's a more Pythonic way of doing the following:

```
A = some list
i = 0
j = 1
for _ in range(1, len(A)):
    #some operation between A[i] and A[j]
    i += 1
    j += 1
```

I feel like this should/could be done differently. Ideas?

EDIT:
Since some are asking for requirements. I wanted a **general-purpose** answer. Maybe to check if A[i], A[j] are between a certain range, or if they're equal. Or maybe I wanted to do a "trickle-up" of elements. The more general, the better.

Comment: do you need access to the indices of the list or would iterating over just the elements without the indices work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) lets you combine multiple iterators:

```
for i,j in zip(range(0,len(A)-1), range(1,len(A))):
    #some operation between A[i] and A[j]
```

you can also use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) on a range object:

```
for i,j in enumerate(range(1,len(A)):
    #some operation between A[i] and A[j]
```

Note that unlike the other answers this gives you access to the *indices* of A not just the items, this is necessary if you want to use any *assignment* to `A[i]` or `A[j]`, for example here is a very basic bubble sort:

```
A = list(range(10))
found1=True
while found1:
    found1=False
    for i,j in enumerate(range(1,len(A))):
        if A[i] < A[j]:
            A[i],A[j] = A[j],A[i]
            found1=True
print(A)
```

this is *only* possible when you iterate over the *indices* of A.

Answer (score 8):

There's a nice little recipe in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for doing this. As a bonus it works with any iterable, not just sequences.

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for current, next_ in pairwise(A):
    # do something
    pass
```

If you need the index as well then just `enumerate` the pairwise iterator.

```
for current_index, (current, next_) in enumerate(pairwise(A)):
    # do something
    pass
```

Comment: what are the return values for enumerate. grossly confused. is it index, value. How does enumerate know if it is index, value or value and nextvalue. ?

Comment: @Whatever You can check the help for enumerate with `help(enumerate)` which details how enumerate works. It's always yields a sequence 2-tuples of `index, element_at_index`. However, I further unpack `element_at_index` into  `current` and `next_` (because that's what `pairwise` produces).

Answer (score 3):

For operation '+':

```
A = [A[i+1]+A[i] for i in range(len(A)-1)]
```

General:

```
A = [operation(A[i], A[i+1]) for i in range(len(A)-1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do :

```
A = some list
for Ai, Aj in zip(A, A[1:]):
    #some operation between A[i] and A[j]
```

Comment: you are no longer iterating over indices but the elements in A

Comment: Yes but if the purpose is to do some operation between Ai and Aj, it seems to work.

Comment: `zip` is a good idea here, assuming you don't need the indices of Ai and Aj. You can also shave off a few characters by doing `zip(A, A[1:])`. When `zip` receives two iterables of different lengths, it only iterates up to the end of the shorter one. So cutting the last element off using `A[:-1]` isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: not if you want to switch the elements in `A[i]` with `A[j]`

Comment: this does not allow for **assignment** to `A[i]` since you do **not keep track of indices**.

Comment: Maybe the person who posted the question can clarify the requirements.

Comment: you also unnecessarily create a copy list (two with `A[:-1]`) in order to iterate which is ridiculously costly for large lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice
A1 = iter(A)
A2 = islice(A, 1, None)
for a1, a2 in zip(A1, A2):
    # do whatever with A[i], A[i+1]
```

`islice` is more generic than using `A[1:]` since it works on iterators (which are not subscriptable) as well. Please note that you need to pass `None` as the third parameter because `islice(iterable, stop)` only returns the first `stop` items of the iterator (hence the name) which is exactly the opposite of what you want, when a third parameter is passed it treats the second as starting position rather than stopping index.

```
islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])  # roughly = iterable[start:stop:step]
islice(iterable, stop)                 # roughly = iterable[:stop]
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for more info.

Now `zip()` emits values till the `shortest` iterator(`A2`) is exhausted. So no worries about the possible `IndexError`.

Comment: `islice(A, n)` doesn't skip `n` items, it stops after `n` items. It should be changed to `islice(A, 1, None)`